# How to save websocket session to redis using the ws library?

Tags: express, websocket, redis, ws

- Newbie to this, I am using [the ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws) in my express node.js server to support websockets
- Currently I just store them to an in memory array
- I would like to store each session in redis
- How do I achieve this?
- [This GitHub issue on their repository doesn't have a solution](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1308)

My current websocket code

```
// https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/express-session-parse/index.js, if you pass a server instance here 'upgrade' handler will crash
const websocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true })

function heartbeat() {
  this.isAlive = true
}

websocketServer.on('connection', (ws, request, client) => {
  ws.isAlive = true
  ws.on('pong', heartbeat)
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    logger.info(`Received message ${msg} from user ${client}`)
    ws.send(true)
  })
})

export default websocketServer
```

Comment: Connection objects (WebSockets) are process specific and cannot be stored to a database in a way that allows these objects to be restored. The Connection objects are very local to the specific machine and specific process to which they belong (unless that process was forked, in which case you might experience a lot of issues).

Comment: then how is socket.io-redis doing it? it uses socket.io-engine right? which uses ws as an underlying layer, cant we associate a uuid to ws instance and then store it?

Comment: Socket.io might be using a hash map, mapping global UUIDs with local WebSocket objects, so it can direct message to a specific WebSocket. However, socket.io does **not** store the WebSocket connection object in Redis... ...focus on the problem you're trying to solve, not on the solution you're trying to implement. What's the actual issue? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @myst scale the websocket connections to more than one ec2 server

Comment: Scaling the server to more than one machine is can be super easy or complicated depending on the server's functionality. Your comment and question doesn't describe this functionality, so it's impossible to help. If I am to guess - to provide pub / sub services from more than one server, you might choose from any number of approaches - one will be to have the server act as a pub/sub proxy between clients and Redis, so Redis sees each server as a single client, like facil.io (in C) and iodine (in Ruby) do.

Answer (score 0):

There’s actually this repository that shows how redis could be used with ws to enable horizontal scaling server.
https://github.com/toiye/ws-redis-test/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31980507)